# What is a word for someone who wants to preserve others' cultures?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm searching for the word for someone who believes in the preservation of other people's cultures. Does anyone know of a good word for this? I don't think "anthropologist" is a good word, as that indicates the study of the cultures, but people can have this belief without studying them.

Comment: I can't distill this into a proper answer, but you may find inspiration at the following Wikipedia articles: [Antiquarian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiquarian), [Cultural heritage preservation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_heritage_management), and [Careers in historic preservation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historic_preservation#Careers) ...

Comment: Another option is "cultural curator."

Comment: Of the existing answers I think "preservationist" is the best. Additionally, I would suggest "[cultural] conservator" or, more freely, "cultural conservationist." All these terms, however, should probably be accompanied by an explanation of how exactly you are using them, since they are not really standard terms for this thing, as far as I know. One more problem is that these terms (especially my "conservator") may suggest some activity toward this goal, not merely belief in it--so, again, be sure to explain your use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try this simple word: *culturalist*. It has a similar meaning to what you're trying to express here:

Wiktionary says that a *[culturalist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/culturalist#English)* subscribes to *[culturalism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/culturalism)*, which is "a belief system that emphasizes the role of culture."

Comment: Culturalist came to mind, but MSWord spellcheck didn't like it, so I thought maybe it was a word that I made up on my own.

Comment: @roviuser MSEnglish != actual English :)

Comment: Also you have the option to add new words to your MS Word dictionary so the spelling check will start liking it again :D

Answer (score 6):

The term I would use is ***cultural preservationist***.

Per [Law Insider](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/cultural-preservation), this involves "the desire to protect and conserve the beliefs, practices, values, customs, traditions, or social behavior significant to a particular group of people."

Comment: +1. Or simply "preservationist."